# How to save file path into a variable in case of Unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

```
storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("--");
    StorageReference dw = storage_ref.Child("Folder/"+PlayerPrefs.GetString("key")+".json");
    
    
   string local_url = Application.dataPath+"/Save Folder/"+storage_ref.Name; 
     // Start downloading a file
    Task task = storage_ref.GetFileAsync(default_path+storage_ref.Name,
   new Firebase.Storage.StorageProgress <DownloadState>((DownloadState state) => {
    // called periodically during the download
   
    Debug.Log(string.Format(
      "Progress: {0} of {1} bytes transferred.",
      state.BytesTransferred,
      state.TotalByteCount
      
    ));
    
  }), CancellationToken.None);

task.ContinueWith(resultTask => {
  if (!resultTask.IsFaulted && !resultTask.IsCanceled) {
    
    Debug.Log("Download finished.");
    
  }
});
```

I've tried to download file form Firebase storage.
But `local_url` file is not created.

I've also tried static string path in `local_url` so solved this problem.

Comment: **Careful**: Do not use `+ "/"` for system file paths. Rather use `Path.Combine` which inserts the correct path separators according to your platform. Could you also post a complete script ... currently I don't understand what exactly your question is

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the documentation page, [Application.dataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) is not guaranteed to be writeable (specifically on iOS it's read only and on Android it's either an APK or OBB [an opaque archive that can't be written into]).

Try switching to [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html):

```
string local_url = $"{Application.persistentDataPath}/Save Folder/{storage_ref.Name}";
```